# Can't update my view method in android app

Tags: android, viewgroup

I am making an app in which I need to update multiple textviews at once. For example:

```
//Just an example int
    int number = 0;
            public void updateViews(View view){

        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
    textView.setText("" + number);    
    }
```

Then let's sat that the number int changes, I need to update the updateViews method so that I don't have to manually update all of the TextViews at once.
When I try to call something like:

```
updateViews();
```

it gives me an error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to provide the error message you're receiving.

Comment: @SG123 You need a logic?

Comment: It says "Update(View) cannot be applied to ()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I figured this out. What I did was something like this:

```
public int number;

Public void add(View view){
number++;
Update();
return false;
}

Public void update(){
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
TextView.setText(""+number);

return false;
}
```

Comment: Trying using String.valueOf(number) instead of "" + number.